# Does Windows Phone 8.0 stream or download videos as Media Element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mediaelement, video-player

XAML

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideoElement" Stretch="Uniform" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

C#:

```
url = "http://smf.blob.core.windows.net/samples/videos/bigbuck.mp4";
mx_videoElement.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
```

If I play a larger video, will the user have to wait until it's fully download it it's streamed (loads while playing)?

What if I open it on the browser too, how does it handle it?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: it plays the video but I am not sure how it's handling it.

Comment: Try with a video of a few hundred MB or larger. If it starts playing after a few seconds, it's downloading while playing. If it takes a while, it's playing after the entire file is downloaded.

Comment: I tried a 200MB MP4 file online and it's taking ~6 seconds to start. Any suggetions for a +500MB MP4 file online?

Comment: That's would be about 33 MB/s or 267 Mbps. I think it's safe to assume that it's downloading while playing.